# Find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, with $J=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $I=J^3=J\cdot J\cdot J$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, ideals

Let $J=\langle x,y\rangle$ and $I=J^3=J\cdot J\cdot J$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$.

Find a basis (manually) of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/I$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

I'm stuck. I have tried to find examples of how to find such a base to try and understand it, but have not really found anything.
So I would be grateful for any hints, ideas, approaches or similar examples to help me understand...

Comment: Can you make a list of non zero polynomial s in the quotient, that is a list of spanning elements? Can you describe the polynomials in $I$?

Answer (score 0):

You have that $J^2=\langle x^2,xy,y^2\rangle$, and $J^3=\langle x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3\rangle$. So in the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/J^2$ a term of the type $a_{ij}x^i y^j=0$ when $i+j\geq 2$. Therefore in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/J^2$ a polynomial $\sum_{ij} a_{ij}x^iy^j$ reduces to

$$ a_{00}+a_{10}x+a_{01}y.$$
With this in mind, can you figure out a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/J^3$ ?

Comment: Does the following make sense? The basis for $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/J^3$: $\lbrace x,y,xy,x^2,y^2 \rbrace$ basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ if $I = \langle x^3,y^3,x^2 y,x y^2\rangle = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I forgot to add a $1$ in the brackets...

Comment: The ideal $I$ can never be $0$, since $x$ and $y$ are transcendental variables (they are not roots of a polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$), so $x^3,y^3\neq 0$ for example. But yes the other claim is correct, that set will be a basis  for the quotient  as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space